# Joining jsonb subQuery using Criteria Builder API and Postgres DB

Tags: java, postgresql, jsonb, criteriabuilder

I have a little problem with building a query using CB and Postgres.
I have a jsonb field and I need a filter on the value item of this json and more items, too.
I have not got too much experience with CB API and I don't know if it is suitable for my problem or not at all.

In any of my solutions CB generate an SQL where **value(jsonb_each_text(pd.dsjson))** expression placed in the where clause and this solution is bleeding.

The naked select what I need is:

```
select
        t1_0.id,
        c1_0.id,
        jsonquery.jsonb_value
    from
        task t1_0 
    join
        campaign c1_0 
            on t1_0.id=c1_0.task_id 
    join (SELECT value(jsonb_each_text(pd.dsjson)) AS jsonb_value, pd.campaign_uuid c_id 
            FROM datasource pd) as jsonquery 
            on c1_0.id = c_id       
    where
        jsonquery.jsonb_value LIKE '%aaa%';
```

really thanks for any help

`... WHERE  value(jsonb_each_text(dsjson)) like "%aaa%"` 
is not working:
**SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE**